# Derive time of diffuse from fick's law

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have a problem to calculate a time to diffuse of a gas through a membrane.

For example, membrane thickness is $2\mu m$, a diffusion coefficient is $2\times10^{-9}$, left side of the membrane has a constant pressure of $100 \,mmHg$, initial right side pressure is $80\,mmHg$, find the time when the right side of the membrane pressure is $100\,mmHg$

I found this equation
$$
t = \frac{x^2}{2D}
$$
where
$t$ is time to diffuse
$x$ is distance to diffuse
$D$ is diffusion coefficient

I wonder where $2$ is come from. I want to understand how to derive the above equation and whether it can be used in my problem.

Comment: Can you please specify the problem more precisely.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I have just edited to include an example in the question.

Comment: Why would the right side pressure change from 80 mm Hg?  Is the right side blocked after time zero?

Comment: @ChesterMiller Yes, it's not infinite. I think the teacher assumes that the concentration gradient in the membrane is linear at t=0.

Comment: So you have a linear concentration gradient at t = 0, running from 100 on the left hand side to 80 on the right hand side, and, at t = 0, you block the rhs in order to allow the concentration to rise up to 100 throughout.

Comment: @ChesterMiller yes.

Answer (score 0):

The exact mathematical solution to this problem would indicate that an infinite time would be required.  However, the "practical" amount of time (the amount of time required for the entire membrane to be > 99 mm) would be relatively short.  An upper bound to the time would be if the entire membrane were at 80 mm initially.

This problem is analogous to transient heat conduction to a slab, the solution to which is given in Transport Phenomena by Bird, et al, Chapter 12. According to the results in Bird, the amount of time required would be $$t=\frac{b^2}{D}$$where b is the membrane thickness.  So your equation is on the right order of magnitude.